# Multi-Valued date range parameter in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I was tasked with replacing old reports made in Crystal Reports since SSRS is the standard we are using. The core functionality of the new SSRS reports works fine but there's one thing missing. It's not insanely important but it's been bugging me. One of the tables in the database I'm working on tracks tasks that have been worked on and stores the Monday of the week they were completed on as a datetime, as well as time spent etc.

Currently my reports allow for the user to choose a start week from a list of Mondays, and an end week. This along with other things are sent to a stored procedure to get the data needed for the report, with the where clause including

```
AND (Table).WeekStartDate BETWEEN (@paramStartWeek) AND (@paramEndWeek)
```

In the older Crystal Reports ones the query and filtering is done entirely in the report instead of a stored procedure. It seems to allow a list of different, specific intervals. If I wanted info from two weeks of 2015 and then 5 weeks from 2018 to appear in the report (for some reason) I could keep adding intervals to a list.

Normally you could do something similar in SSRS by setting the parameter to accept multiple values and parsing the string it creates in the stored procedure, but if i selected multiple start and end dates as two separate parameters there would be nothing saying which start went with which end.

Most of examples of this I've seen only allowed for predetermined amounts of time ("One month ago, three months ago, a year ago") but I would like for it to be any week needed.

The person I'm doing this for would like most of the filtering done outside of the report, so I'm wondering if anyone knows an easy way to get a list of specific date ranges from SSRS into a stored procedure.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not be possible to do. If you could transform multi-selects into XML it may be possible but a) probably difficult to do b) I don't believe SSRS has this ability. To my knowledge you best option would be to have multiple start and end date params (i.e. start1, end1) and your proc could gather those multiple date ranges. However it would be static in this way - if you made five parameter sets then they could obviously only pull five date ranges. Perhaps better would be to ask why they couldn't just run the report multiple times for different date ranges in the first place

Comment: Running it multiple times for different ranges is what we settled with because the use of multiple wouldn't come up that often. I wanted to see if there was a solution because i'm being kind of a perfectionist but it's definitely not the kind of issue i would want to spend hours working out